# How can i add images to python using the visual studio?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, filenotfounderror

When i try to add images on python with using visual studio, Visual studio makes problem like: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:. But when i run the program with python IDLE, the code is running.

Why visual studio makes this problem i cannot figure out. if anyone know can please help me to figure out ( I'm using pillow library for adding images.)

Comment: Use an absolute pathname for the relevant file. Chances are that the working directories for VSCode and Python IDLE are different

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved the problem by first opening the image folder and adding the file to the explorer section on VSCode. Maybe it will help anyone who encounters this problem.